# how to check for null value in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting Object Null Reference error. I tried checking for null as done below but I am still getting the error.

```
List<Data> gvdta = (List<Data>)Session["Items"];
switch (this.dd_search.SelectedValue)
{
    case "emp":                
    var tb = (from ad in gvdta
              where ad!=null & ad.emp.ToLower().Contains(this.txt_Search.Text.ToLower())
              select ad);
       gvdta = tb.ToList();            
    break;
}
```

Is there any other way? Please help.Thank you.

Comment: have you checked if gvdta is null?

Comment: may be your `SelectedValue` is null , and it should be `&&` not `&`

Comment: Or if `ad.emp` or `this.txt_search.Text` is null?

Comment: Use `&&` operator in `where ad!=null && ad.emp.ToLower().Contains(this.txt_Search.Text.ToLower())`. `&` is bitwise operator where both sides will be always evaluated.

Comment: @Fabio it should be an answer

Comment: @Maarten it was a silly mistake, I just changed `where ad!=null` to `where ad.emp!= null` and also used &&. Its working fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `&&` operator in

```
where ad!=null && ad.emp.ToLower().Contains(this.txt_Search.Text.ToLower()).
```

`&` is bitwise operator where both sides will be always evaluated. From [& Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator)

> The & operator **evaluates both operators** regardless of the first one's
>   value.

[From && Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator)

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool
>   operands, **but only evaluates its second operand if necessary**.

Comment: I just changed `where ad!=null` to `where ad.emp!= null` and also used &&. Its working fine now. Thanks.